# Converting the slice of a string inside an index in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

For a school project, I have to make a blackjack game, long story short, part of my hand-evaluation code involves me incrementing a variable by the slice of a string selected by slicing a list.

My code is:

```
player_hand_sum =+ int(player_hand[0[:0]])
```

Which returns a 'int' object is not subscriptable error.

Any ideas as to how I can remedy this?

TIA

EDIT: "player_hand" is a list containing between two and five strings.

Comment: What does the player_hand look like

Comment: What are you slicing? From where to where?

Comment: Your current code doesn't increment player_hand_sum instead it assigns the value to it, this is because the '=+' should be '+='.

Comment: I'm attempting to slice out the first character of the first index of a list.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `player_hand[0][:1]`, but it's hard to tell from your code.

Comment: Alberick's right, I've made an error that I seem to keep repeating, I typed "=+" instead of "+=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from inside the slice -

```
0[:0]
```

You are trying to subscript `0` there, which is throwing the `int` is not subscriptable error. Example to show the same error -

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l[0[:0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

You want to do `[0][:1]` instead , Example -

```
player_hand_sum += int(player_hand[0][:1]])
```

---

Also, another issue , `=+` (though valid syntax) does not increment the value for the name on the left side with the one on the right side (it just directly assigns), to do increment you need to use `+=` .

Comment: `=+` does do something: it assigns the value on the right to the target on the left.  That's different than what `+=` does, but it is doing something quite consequential.

Comment: Ok What I meant was it does not do what OP thinks it would. Reworded. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my lack of clarity, it's my first time posting.